# Why does runtimeconfig.json contain includedFrameworks instead of frameworks?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, publish

**Hello,**

I have an AspNet Core application which gets published like this:

```
dotnet publish -c release MyApplication.csproj
```

the problem is, that the generated `MyApplication.runtimeconfig.json` dose contain a `includedFrameworks` Tag instead of `frameworks`.

This is what I get:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.10"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

but I would expect:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "frameworks": [         // <-------------
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.10"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell my why `dotnet` is doing this, bzw how to generate it the right way?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add following parameters:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -p:UseAppHost=false --self-contained false
```

In my case the application is hosted in IIS.

Comment: All I needed from this was "--self-contained false".  My .Net core 6.0 CLI app hadn't been running when built in a docker alpine instance.  I still can't execute the produced exe, but can execute "dotnet myApp.dll"

Comment: In my case I had publish command with the `--no-build` flag using dotnet 7 sdk ...
Removing it, fixed the output.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen when you publish multiple builds of the same product. For example, if you deploy self-contained and not-self-contained versions. You need to be careful how you do it. For example you **from ZERO**, publish a full, self-contained  version. The project builds. Then you decided that next version will be partial. You include `--no-build` because supposedly, it already has build. And this is where you have this issue

As in this sequence

```
publish yourProject.csproj --configuration Release --framework net6.0 --output output\linux64-full --runtime linux-x64-full --self-contained true

publish yourProject.csproj --configuration Release --framework net6.0 --output output\linux64 --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained false --no-build
```

The issue is, when you add `--no-build` presumably to save some time, you also don't modify your `yourProject.runtimeconfig.json`. **The good news**, is that even if you remove the `--no-build` switch, you still don't recompile your DLLs. But you do rewrite the `yourProject.runtimeconfig.json`

The bottom line, while adding or not adding `--self-contained` switch does regulate the creation of `runtimeconfig.json`, it depends on other other conditions such if you build or don't build the code during publish and if you do it while switching the output mode.